# Nginx: Static asset paths not rendered properly with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm having difficulties configuring reverse proxy to bring user from `http://localhost/nexus/` to `http://localhost:8081/`.

My current `nginx.conf` looks like this:-

```
worker_processes 4;

events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /nexus/ {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/;

            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit `http://localhost/nexus/`, it partially renders the page.

When I inspected the HTML source code, I noticed the javascript links, image links and stylesheet links are not constructed properly.

For example, I'm seeing this:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/static/rapture/resources/loading-prod.css?_v=3.3.1-01">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/static/rapture/baseapp-prod.js?_v=3.3.1-01"></script>
<img id="loading-logo" src="http://localhost/static/rapture/resources/images/loading-logo.png?_v=3.3.1-01"/>
```

... but, it should be this:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/nexus/static/rapture/resources/loading-prod.css?_v=3.3.1-01">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/nexus/static/rapture/baseapp-prod.js?_v=3.3.1-01"></script>
<img id="loading-logo" src="http://localhost/nexus/static/rapture/resources/images/loading-logo.png?_v=3.3.1-01"/>
```

How should my `nginx.conf` look to get the rest of the page rendered properly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you need to change URL in generated HTML you need to change your application which generates this HTML. Otherwise you can configure `ngingx` to serve static files directly with 'location /static' pointing to your static files directory.

Comment: I can't change the generated HTML because it's a different web software by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your `nginx` to serve static files directly:

```
location /static {
  root /path/to/static/files;
}
```

The `nginx` process will need read permission to all files in the `static` sub-tree and to its parent directories.

Comment: While it works, it is causing a problem because I have other web software running on the different base path and it too is also use `/static` for their asset files.

Comment: Then I recommend to look at your application again and find a way to tell it that it is running with prefix /nexus, so it generates correct URLs.

Comment: Actually, you can try changing proxy_pass to http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/ - it is possible that application detects its base URL automatically

Comment: You are absolutely right. I configured Nexus to have a custom context path and change the proxy_pass to match that ( `http://localhost:8081/nexus` )... and it works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolved it:

1. change contex root from  "`/`" to "`/nexus`" in `nexus/conf/nexus-default.properties` and resart
2. change the url in `nginx` accordingly and restart